# Using boost::intrusive_ptr with a nested classes

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, smart-pointers, nested-class

Specifically, I need to declare (as I understand it) `intrusive_ptr_{add_ref,release}` as friends of my referenced class:

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
using boost::intrusive_ptr;

class Outer {
public:

    //user-exposed interface goes here

protected:
    class Inner {
    public:
        Inner():refct(0){}
        virtual ~Inner(){}

        //machinery goes here

        size_t refct;
    };

    friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_release(Inner *p);
    friend void boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Inner *p);

    intrusive_ptr<Inner> handle;

};

namespace boost {

    void intrusive_ptr_release(Outer::Inner *p){
        if ((p->refct -= 1) <= 0){
            delete p;
        }
    }

    void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Outer::Inner *p){
        p->refct++;
    }

};
```

I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to make this compile and keep the access that I want. My main problem is that gcc seems to be upset that "boost::intrusive_ptr_release(Outer::Inner *p) should have been declared in namespace boost".

I see from [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsmartptr.aspx#intrusive_ptr%20-%20lightweight%20shared%20pointer) that the intrusive_ptr helpers are forward declared inside of namespace boost-- but I *can't* forward declare them, because as I understand it, nested classes (i.e. "Inner", which these functions refer to) can only be forward-declared *inside* their outer classes, and that's where the friend declaration has to go too.

O greater C++ gurus, what is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put them in `namespace boost`, you can put them in the same namespace as your `class Outer` and they'll be found through argument dependent lookup.

> Every new intrusive_ptr instance increments the reference count by using an **unqualified** call to the function intrusive_ptr_add_ref, passing it the pointer as an argument.

Comment: You're right; that does work. One of the docs I was reading explicitly said that the friend functions must be in the boost namespace (which is supported by the example I linked to), so I just took it for granted. Don't know why I didn't try that sooner. Thanks!

Comment: The keyword here is "argument dependent lookup" (commonly referred to as Koenig's lookup or just ADL). Have a google on it, it's worth understanding why such feature exists in C++ and how it works.